# Comparing topologies

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. How to compare $\tau_{C(Y,X)}$ and $\tau_{co}$?

(By definition, $C(Y,X):=\{f:Y\rightarrow X|\textit{$f$ is continuous}\}\subset X^Y$. 
For $K\subset Y$ and $U\subset X$ is defined $M(K,U):=\{f\in C(Y, X)|f(K)\subset U\}$. Compact-open topology $\tau_{co}$ on
$C(Y,X)$ is topology defined by subbasis $S_{co}:=\{M(K, U)|K\in K_Y, U\in\tau_X\}$).

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me write $C$ for $C(X,Y)$ equipped with the compact open topology, and $C'$ for $C(X,Y)$ equipped with subspace topology of the product topology on $Y^X$.

> The canonical bijection
>   $$\theta:C\to C',\quad f\mapsto f$$
>   is continuous, i.e., the topology induced from the product topology is coarser than the compact open topology.

Indeed, $\theta$ is continuous *iff* $i\circ\theta:C\to C'\to Y^X$ is continuous (where $i:C\to Y^X$ is the canonical injection) *iff* $p_x\circ i\circ\theta:C\to C'\to Y^X\to Y$ is continuous for all $x\in X$. If $U\subset Y$ is an open subset, then
$$\big(p_x\circ i\circ\theta\big)^{-1}(U)=M(\lbrace x\rbrace,U)$$
is a subbasic open subset of $C$ by definition of the compact open topology (singletons are compact.)

Comment: Thanks on swift answer. So, $\tau_{C(X,Y)}\subset\tau_{co}$, but does the opposite hold (are those topologies equivalent or not)?

Comment: Generally, the compact open topology is strictly finer. I might be wrong, but the only case when they coincide is when the only compact subsets of $X$ are finite, or $Y$ is trivial.

Comment: Is there any counterexample which shows that other inclusion doesn't hold in general case?